# Copying an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, copy

I am trying to copy an array.

```
class Myobject 
{
  int nb; 
  string name; 
  Myobject* next;
  Myobject(int nb, string name) {this->name=name; this->nb=nb; this->next=NULL;}
};

Myobject **array;
array= new Myobject*[100];
```

how can I make a deep copy of the Myobject ** and thus be able to modify one of the instances.

Comment: thanks for accepting the answer, please take a look at the update as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be up to date, use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) for which C++ is really good for.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Myobject : std::enable_shared_from_this< Myobject >
{
  int nb; 
  std::string name; 
  std::shared_ptr<Myobject> next;
  Myobject(int nb, std::string name) { this->name=name; this->nb=nb; }
  ~Myobject() { std::cout << "deleting " << nb << " " << name << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr< Myobject > > arr;
    arr.push_back(std::make_shared< Myobject >(1,"first"));
    arr.push_back(std::make_shared< Myobject >(2,"second"));

    for (auto obj: arr) {
        std::cout << obj->nb << " " << obj->name << std::endl;
    }

    arr[0]->next = arr[1];
};
```

[outputting](http://ideone.com/Q4QKpw)

```
1 first
2 second
deleting 1 first
deleting 2 second
```

and you don't need to care much about memory management at first. Your example without proper care would generate memory leaks.

Update: forgot to mention, if you have circular references, beware, you might get memory leaks using `shared_ptr`s as well. If that should be the case, you might avoid that by switching to `weak_ptr`s → [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)

Answer (score 0):

You may add this (deep)-copy constructor:

```
Myobject(const Myobject& rhs) :
    nb(rhs.nb),
    name(rhs.name),
    next(rhs.next == NULL ? NULL : new Myobject(*rhs.next))
{}
```

You will probably have to add a correct destrutor to avoid memory leak...
If possible, I suggest to use `std::list<Myobject>` instead

Comment: Yes thank you for the constructor. But I don't understand how to copy the whole array? with a for loop? (I cannot use std containers because it is an homework).

Comment: david.pcx's anwser show you how to do it... But I suggest to use `std::vector` instead by the way

Answer (score 0):

Allocate array and loop to copy.

```
NewMyobject **newarray = new Myobject*[100];
for (int i = 0 ; i < 100; ++i)
  newarray[i] = new MyObject(array[i]);
```

Object must have a copy constructor.